# Interpolating missing points in 3D data-set

Tags: 3d, interpolation, surfaces

Given the following `x,y,z` points (`z` is actually a signal strength indicator in dBm):

```
63  371 -21
142 371 -9
233 374 -18
288 371 -36
310 373 -38
349 374 -39
415 348 -44
507 334 -49
689 337 -56
635 254 -57
422 284 -42
380 278 -39
281 280 -39
214 299 -34
146 285 -30
81  302 -39
76  246 -39
80  214 -44
137 200 -44
64  134 -48
73  87  -48
200 101 -46
230 202 -44
246 105 -53
285 109 -53
278 191 -50
334 87  -54
395 189 -56
513 208 -58
510 99  -61
553 101 -62
593 100 -65
634 101 -64
679 102 -68
731 196 -70
```

How would I go about interpolating the missing `z` values for the remaining points, assuming they cover an area that is 800x400 units? (The area is of course arbitrary, but for this data-set it should suffice).

I realize that this question is not a simple as it first seems. My goal is to end up with a numerical representation of the entire space (ideally a 2D array holding the Z values, in C#, for those who are interested) however I'm not even sure how to fit a suitable surface to these points. Once complete, the 2D array should hold a predicted signal strength at every x,y point. A single, "best fit" plane will not suffice, as the point of this is to generate a signal strength heat map with usable values at each point, based on measurements at various points on the floor plan. In other words, the attenuation from various walls/furniture/etc. must be taken into account.

Cheers

Comment: Looks like you need to extrapolate a little, too. One high powered method I know is called kriging... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging

Though, you may get better suggestions on the Computational Science site... http://scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: You're right, given the area I specified some extrapolation would certainly be necessary, thanks for pointing that out. I'll have a look at Kriging and post this on scicomp as well.

Comment: You can also try finding an interpolating function that fits your data, say using a [polyharmonic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyharmonic_spline) ([for example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11817/484)), and then evaluating it at the missing points.

Comment: @RahulNarain: My (basic) understanding of splines is that they are meant to smooth data, correct? I worry that smoothing might, for example, end up squashing a sharp peak even though it shouldn't.

Comment: That's the difference between [interpolating splines and approximating splines](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~sequin/CS184/IMGS/SplineTypes.JPG). If you fit a thin plate spline to *interpolate* your data, it will pass through all the data points and so it can't compress extrema.

Comment: Good to know, @Rahul! Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to construct a [Delaunay triangulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delaunay_triangulation) for the 2D point cloud, extruding this triangulation to the 3D values. Each triangle has a plane equation which can be used to find the rest of the $z$ values for "new" points $x,y$ in the corresponding triangle.

Note the equation for the plane defined by three points is given by:
 $$\begin{vmatrix}
x   - x_1 & y   - y_1 & z   - z_1 \\
x_2 - x_1 & y_2 - y_1 & z_2 - z_1 \\
x_3 - x_1 & y_3 - y_1 & z_3 - z_1
\end{vmatrix}  = 0$$

Comment: At first glance this appears to be very much what I'm looking for. The idea of somehow drawing triangles between close points crossed my mind, but I wasn't sure how to go about accomplishing that. I'll look over the Delaunay stuff and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Delaunay triangulation looks to be exactly what I need! Cheers

Comment: I haven't done any linear algebra in quite a while... Would you be able to point me towards a resource for solving for _z_?